# Is't Possible to update the ContentDocumentId field value of ContentVersion in Before Insert trigger?

Tags: before-trigger, contentversion, contentdocument, insert

I would like to update the ContentDocumentId of ContentVersion record in the before insert trigger.
Is this possible? If it's not possible can anyone please explain the reason for it?

Update:

When a user uploads a file from the standard upload file button. I need to check if there are existing files with the same name. it should create a new contentversion record in existing file instead of creating new file

```
trigger ContentVersionTrigger on ContentVersion(before insert) {
     for (ContentVersion conVer : trigger.new) {
          conVer.ContentDocumentId  = docId; //assign different ConteentDocument id from here.
     }
}
```

Comment: You can check in documentation - ContentDocumentId field is not updateable (https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.234.0.object_reference.meta/object_reference/sforce_api_objects_contentversion.htm)

Comment: @kurunve can you help me where its exactly

Comment: This is apparently an [X-Y Problem](https://xyproblem.info/). You've asked about how to do a particular thing without explaining why you need it. If you ask about your core problem, we can probably help you with that.

Comment: @sfdcfox When a user uploads a file from the standard upload file button. I need to check if there are existing files with the same name. it should create a new contentversion record in the existing file instead of creating a new file.

Comment: @sfdcfox so from contentversion before insert trigger, I am trying to change the contentdocumentId field.